# how to convert an Int into Editable?

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, android-edittext

i have this code

```
private fun plus(){
    val num1 = num1TextE.text.toString().toInt()
    val num2 = num2TextE.text.toString().toInt()
    if(checkEditTextEmpty()){
        resultText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        var result = num1 + num2
        resultText.text = "Result is $result"
        num1TextE.text = // make it equal to result 
    }
}
```

and i want to assign the `result` value to `num1TextE` editText, and i tried with `toString()` but it says required !Editable found String , i tried with `Integer.parseInt()` but it still didn't worked !

Comment: use setText() method

Comment: Oh damn that was simple, thanks it worked, i thought all "set and get" method are java things and kotlin simply use "text" as i thought "setText()" works the same as "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property is a getter and maybe a setter for data. The synthetic property created from java code now behaves like:

```
var text: Editable
```

even though the setter actually accepts a `CharSequence`, which is a supertype of `Editable`. So you'd have to use the setter directly, instead of accessing it through the property:

```
num1TextE.setText("$result")
```